# Vue JS: generate random numbers for invoice

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i wanted to know the best way for generating random numbers for invoice and it shouldn't be duplicated .. in my project i'm posting invoice number for each user into API and ofc i should completely avoid duplication ... is there a way to do this in Vue js?

below i tried this code but i believe it might duplicate by chance :\

```js
const Random = '0' + Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000000)+ moment(new Date()).format('DDMMYY');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? You will find plenty of "non-repeating random number generators" here on SO

Comment: _"i wanted to know the best way..."_ - Without a specific definition of _"best"_ this will only attract opinions -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) - _"if you know a good source..."_ - as already mentioned you will find plenty of answers here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

As time cannot be repeated, you can use `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: But if you want make an id, it's better to use an string with the UUID pattern, where it's almost impossible to repeat. This site have some examples: https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

Answer (score 0):

Use UUID v4

1. Install and import UUID

> ```
> import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
> ```

2. Set invoice ID

> ```
> invoice.id = uuidv4(); // ⇨ '14cd6bcd-bbfd-4a2d-3b5d-ab8dfcbd4dea'
> ```

3. At the backend side, don't forget to check that the invoice id is not already used.
4. Best way is to define a database unique key.